# how to create a f# windows application (no cmd window) without visual studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, f#, text-editor, visual-studio-project

Is it possible to create a Winforms Application in F#, where no CMD Window will be opened, without using Visual Studio?

I know that I could simply create a VS Project and set the 'Output type' to 'Windows Application'. But I really like the approach of simply firing up any kind of text editor and start hacking away.

Comment: The easiest way would be to follow some of the linux instructions and just figure how to change the paths to point to fsharpc.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use --target:WinExe in compiler options
fsc source.fsx --target:WinExe

Answer (score 1):

Open any editor end write something like this:

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

// Create form, button and add button to form
let form = new Form(Text = "Hello world!")
let btn = new Button(Text = "Click here")
form.Controls.Add(btn)

// Register event handler for button click event
btn.Click.Add(fun _ ->
  // Generate random color and set it as background
  let rnd = new Random()
  let r, g, b = rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)
  form.BackColor <- Color.FromArgb(r, g, b) )

// Show the form (in F# Interactive)
form.Show()
// Run the application (in compiled application)
Application.Run(form)
```

Save it as file with extension `.fsx` (ex "`Form.fsx`")
Run "`fsi Form.fsx`" from command line. (Make sure that fsi.exe in your PATH)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe I was to vague in my question. My intentions where to create a exe file.
@sam 's answer is exactly what I was looking for.